# Change format of a list when printed in python

Tags: python, list, django-queryset

I am pulling a Query set and putting into a list as below -

```
data = Data.objects.all().values_list('number')
data_list = list(data)
print(data_list)

[('1',), ('2',), ('3',)]
```

But I would like to change this to be formatted as a list without the brackets like below -

```
[1,2,3]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of list comprehension:-

```
val=[(str(list(x)[0])) for x in val]
```

Now print val you will get your desired output:-

```
[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can work with `flat=True` to the [**`.values_list(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list), to make a list of scalars instead of tuples:

```
Data.objects.values_list('number', flat=True)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer- using the appropriate django api call